# is it possible to create a rest web api with pure django?

Tags: django, rest

I can't figure out if it's possible to create a django api without the django rest framework because I'm having troubles with csrf token while receiving my POST datas.

Is it possible to disable this because I can't use django csrf token management in my javascript electron app ?

Comment: "I'm having troubles" - if you can specify *what* you did and what those "troubles" are exactly, maybe we could help. As your question is now, it is likely to get closed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

There is documentation on how to pass the CSRF token using Ajax.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request

Or you can disable CSRF using the csrf_exempt decorator:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt